# Balanced column-fill on chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have a series of `inline-block` divs displayed in 2 columns using CSS columns.

I want the columns to be balanced (5 items on each side for example).

Without `inline-block` it works fine. However it sometimes breaks in the middle of one of my elements. Adding `inline-block` fixes this issue but the columns are no longer balanced in Chrome. In Firefox it works fine.

According to this article (https://css-tricks.com/guide-responsive-friendly-css-columns/#article-header-id-9) it's supposed to be balanced by default unless I set a height. I did not set a height, but I suspect that `inline-block` leads to the same condition.

The `column-fill` property is supposed to fix this, but unsupported by Chrome.

Is there a polyfill or workaround I can use?

Comment: Will you please express your problem in https://jsfiddle.net

Comment: July 2016... I don't even remember the problem or if I ever solved it.

Answer (score 3):

Try using `display: flex` instead of `display: inline-block`. You don't need to use anything else from Flex, but somehow it behaves similarly to `inline-block` and it works with `column-fill: balance` in both Chrome and Firefox (in Chrome you may need to use also `break-inside: avoid`). It may not work for all cases, but I had a similar issue and it worked for me

Comment: The `break-inside: avoid` solved a vexing layout problem for me. Thanks!

Comment: This is really the only good solution and I'm surprised it was buried this deep down. There's a number of similar questions to this ("css column-count empty column") and this completely solved the problem for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't really recommend using inline-block

I think you should try this alternatives

- Bootstrap Grid : https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp
- Width using percentage : https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_width.asp

And for responsive website, consider using media query

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it with `display: list-item` and `list-style: none` on the parent container so i didnt have to set all children to `display: inline`. Just for future reference.